# Can you tell if a view is indexing?

Tags: couchdb

I would like to know if a view is indexing so I can give the users some indication rather than having them waiting.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit `/_active_tasks` if there is indexing going on then you'll have a `"type": "indexer"` task running.